# Script not loading in webview android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am trying to load java script in android webview.

I load it from assets folder but it is showing blank page.
here is my script

```
<script> app=\"livecricket.sulekha.com\"; mo=\"1\"; nt=\"n\"; wi =\"w\"; co =\"2\"; ad=\"1\";</script><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://livecricket.sulekha.com/cricket/widgets/script/scoreWidgets.js?cver=3-0-1-8.366736192150111738\"></script>
```

My JAva code -

```
wabeview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

I also added internet permission.

Where i may be doing wrong. Please help me.

Comment: I think you need webChromeClient

Answer (score 1):

Did you added this line?

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Checked browser settings for javascript enabled?

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand you. "browser settings" ?

Comment: Yes. have you enabled javascript in your mobile browser i.e. Webkit?

Comment: I never did that.How can i do that? I am using webview not browser that's why i am getting confused. I already did - webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); Please help me.